# Fully redundant router

Tags: router

I am working on a system for field experiments. I would like to create an Ethernet network that includes multiple computers. In this case, the router becomes a single point of failure.

One solution is to create two identical systems but this is a very expensive solution.

I am looking for a router with built-in redundancy. I saw router with dual power supply but I am not sure this is enough. Is there a fully redundant router? basically two routers in one where I as user connect a single line from each client but in case the router fails it has its own mitigation program switching to a redundant component?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a *router* for a LAN. You need a switch.

In order to ensure redundancy, you can have **two switches**. If each device has two network adapters, each device would be connected to each switch.

There are, then, different strategies.

- You may keep the switches isolated from each other, and consider that you have **two different networks**.
- Or you may connect both switches together and use **LAG** in order to pretend that each device has a single connection to the network, disregarding the fact that there are two physical connections.

I believe that the second solution is easier and more flexible, but I don't have too much skills in network stuff, so ask for advice on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). Also, switches which support LAG are rather expensive, so this may not be a solution for you.

Note that with two switches, you are still at risk that some of the device adapters stop working, and at the same time, the *other* switch stops working as well. If this is an issue, you may have, say, four interconnected switches, forming a **[switching loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop)**—a technique often used to ensure redundancy. With four network adapters for every device, you reduce a lot the risk of losing connectivity to a device even in an event of a simultaneous breakage of a network adapter and a switch.